# SQL query takes more than an hour to execute for 200k rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ssms

I have two tables each with around 200,000 rows. I have run the query below and it still hasn't completed after running for more than an hour. What could be the explanation for this?

```
SELECT 
    dbo.[new].[colom1],
    dbo.[new].[colom2],
    dbo.[new].[colom3],
    dbo.[new].[colom4],  
    dbo.[new].[Value] as 'nieuwe Value',
    dbo.[old].[Value] as 'oude Value'
FROM dbo.[new]
JOIN dbo.[old] 
    ON dbo.[new].[colom1] = dbo.[old].[colom1] 
    and dbo.[new].[colom2] = dbo.[old].[colom2] 
    and dbo.[new].[colom3] = dbo.[old].[colom3] 
    and dbo.[new].[colom4] = dbo.[old].[colom4] 
where dbo.[new].[Value] <> dbo.[old].[Value]
```

from comment;

[image: Execution plan]

[image: Table structure]

Comment: You are probably getting locked. Try to use with (nolock) to verify. Just to be sure, please also add the execution plan.

Comment: 200,000 rows at a time is too much and performance should be slow. Try using pagination and show 10 - 20 data in one page. This might help a little.

Comment: I cant make an executing plan, because it wont execute the query, so I will delete some rows first, bare with me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131357/discussion-between-dudu-markovitz-and-wouter-de-jong).

Comment: @Fredou, why did you suspect the NULLs?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz screenshot is showing nullable field being used in the join / where clause

Comment: @Fredou - yes it is, but why did you think it might be an issue?

Comment: The problems was that my table was full of NULL values.... -.-

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz when playing with null in join/where clause you have to be careful.

Comment: @Fredou - were you familiar with the behaviour I am describing in my answer?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz no exactly but i was going to suggest to handle null in the join clause, doing it in the where does work too

Comment: @Fredou - I would love to meet with the guy that was responsible to this "feature" :-)

Comment: @wouterdejong, be explicit too with the join, put **INNER JOIN** not **JOIN**, default in **INNER** ... but it's better when it is explicit

Comment: @Fredou better how? The only way I can think of is from a readability perspective for people who don't know that `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are functionally identical...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that for an equality join on a single column, the rows with NULL value in the join key are being filtered out, **but this is not the case for joins on multiple columns**.
As a result, the hash join complexity is changed from O(N) to O(N^2).

======================================================================

In that context I would like to recommend a great article written by **Paul White** on similar issues -
[Hash Joins on Nullable Columns](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/11/sql-plan/hash-joins-on-nullable-columns)

======================================================================

I have generated a small simulation of this use-case and I encourage you to test your solutions.

```
create table mytab1 (c1 int null,c2 int null)
create table mytab2 (c1 int null,c2 int null)

;with t(n) as (select 1 union all select n+1 from t where n < 10)
insert into mytab1 select null,null from t t0,t t1,t t2,t t3,t t4

insert into mytab2 select null,null from mytab1

insert into mytab1 values (111,222);
insert into mytab2 values (111,222);
```

---

```
select * from mytab1 t1 join mytab2 t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1 and t1.c2 = t2.c2
```

---

For the OP query we should remove rows with NULL values in any of the join key columns.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.[new].[colom1],
    dbo.[new].[colom2],
    dbo.[new].[colom3],
    dbo.[new].[colom4],  
    dbo.[new].[Value] as 'nieuwe Value',
    dbo.[old].[Value] as 'oude Value'
FROM dbo.[new]
JOIN dbo.[old] 
    ON dbo.[new].[colom1] = dbo.[old].[colom1] 
    and dbo.[new].[colom2] = dbo.[old].[colom2] 
    and dbo.[new].[colom3] = dbo.[old].[colom3] 
    and dbo.[new].[colom4] = dbo.[old].[colom4] 
where dbo.[new].[Value] <> dbo.[old].[Value]
    and dbo.[new].[colom1]  is not null
    and dbo.[new].[colom2]  is not null
    and dbo.[new].[colom3]  is not null
    and dbo.[new].[colom4]  is not null
    and dbo.[old].[colom1]  is not null
    and dbo.[old].[colom2]  is not null
    and dbo.[old].[colom3]  is not null
    and dbo.[old].[colom4]  is not null
```

Answer (score -1):

Using EXCEPT join, you only have to make the larger HASH join on those values that have changed, so much faster:

```
/*
create table [new] ( colom1  int, colom2  int, colom3  int, colom4  int, [value]  int)
create table [old] ( colom1  int, colom2  int, colom3  int, colom4  int, [value]  int)

insert old values (1,2,3,4,10)
insert old values (1,2,3,5,10)
insert old values (1,2,3,6,10)
insert old values (1,2,3,7,10)
insert old values (1,2,3,8,10)
insert old values (1,2,3,9,10)


insert new values (1,2,3,4,11)
insert new values (1,2,3,5,10)
insert new values (1,2,3,6,11)
insert new values (1,2,3,7,10)
insert new values (1,2,3,8,10)
insert new values (1,2,3,9,11)
*/

select n.colom1, n.colom2 , n.colom3, n.colom4, n.[value] as newvalue, o.value as oldvalue
from new n
inner join [old] o on n.colom1=o.colom1 and n.colom2=o.colom2 and n.colom3=o.colom3 and n.colom4=o.colom4
inner join 
(
select colom1, colom2 , colom3, colom4, [value] from new
except
select colom1, colom2 , colom3, colom4, [value] from old
) i on n.colom1=i.colom1 and n.colom2=i.colom2 and n.colom3=i.colom3 and n.colom4=i.colom4
```